# Always need to update frames for a custom view in Interface Builder

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

I wrote a custom IBDesignable class that is basically a collection of other views (a few labels, and image, etc). I override the intrinsicContentSize property so that auto layout can manage it properly:

```
override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
{
    let greater = label_Title.frameBottom > headerView.frameBottom ? label_Title.frameBottom : headerView.frameBottom
    let size = CGSize(width: headerView.width, height: greater)
    print("intrinsicContentSize: \(size)")
    return size
}
```

It works, but there's a caveat. Whenever I open a storyboard that has this view in it, it gets some crazy frame size and I have to hit the "Update Frames" button to get it to size properly again. Is there a step I'm missing that is causing Interface Builder to be confused?